# Command/query pattern differences

Tags: c#

One newbie question: what is the difference between query/queryHandler and command/commandHandler design pattern?

Comment: "Command and Query" are likely references to [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) style architectures. There isn't one standard 'reference framework' for the architecture, so you'll need to be more specific about what you mean.

Comment: I have a project where in business layer are 'commands' 'queries' and 'handlers' and I couldn't see any differences. Maybe one that all queries returns something when some of the commands are just actions. So I'm curious if there are some rules about it.

Comment: The difference, as Ross explains, is that the data does not need necessarily need to be read from the same place to which it is written - this has important benefits in scalability and performance, although possibly with latency impacts of eventual consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barely anything. Commands are one way and don't return anything and guaranteed delivery. Queries, obviously, return a data set of some kind via a data transaction object.

They both follow different paths in a CQRS pattern. Commands are write, Queries are read. Each command or query has a handler which is instantiated when the command or query is received by the message queue. There are many ways to implemented CQRS, but the premise is that Commands (writes) and Queries (read) remain separate.